# Close the div when mouse is clicked outside. (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, show-hide

I have the below html code where there are 3 buttons. One for 'Generate table' and other two for undo and redo features. This is displayed in a line.

When user shrinks the page, these 3 get tied up in a ribbon. A box icon appears now. When user clicks on box icon, i get a dropdown showing 'generate table' buton, undo and redo buttons.

If i now click outside of this div, the dropdown should close automatically. however, it doesnot close at this moment. Anyone please have a look and suggest me how to proceed.

```
<ribbon class="panel" ng-class="group">
        <div class="panelListView" ng-class="ribbonDirectives?'panelListViewBlock':''">
                <button ng-click="">Generate Table</button>               
                <undo-symbol ng-click=""></undo-symbol>
                <redo-symbol ng-click=""></redo-symbol>  
        </div>

        <group class="panelGrouped" ng-if="showGrouped == true" ng-click="showRibbon()"></group>

</ribbon>
```

Comment: Never used the this directive before, but have you tried using ng-blur on the ribbon? Ng-blur might stop ng-click on your child elements from firing however... the workaround is to use ng-mousedown instead of ng-click in the child elements.

Comment: @leo- those are the directive created by me. custom directives... i need a way to close my dropdown when i click anywhr outside... in a similar way how dropdown items using select closes when clicked outside

Comment: I see, did you try ng-blur? If that doesn't work you can try handling $document.on('click', fn) in your custom directive